# Events at the different times in one sentence

Tags: past-tense

The apple was green two months ago, and it was red one month ago, and now it is brown.

Is “the apple was green and red” a correct expression even though it wasn’t green and red at the same time, but at the different times? Or should I say “the apple was green and was red”?

Comment: "The apple changed from green to red..."

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes, you are right, but is “the apple was green and red on two different months” acceptable?

Comment: 'The apple was green and red' defaults (even though the colours would usually be listed in the reverse order) to referencing a bicoloured apple. Using the expression to mean 'The apple was green and then red' is incorrect not on grammatical grounds but as it violates a Gricean maxim (_avoid misleading phraseology; avoid ambiguous phraseology_).